# First query after mysql reboot is slow

Tags: mysql, bash, myisam

I am not as experienced with the backend of mysql and am having the following situation.

Each night I have a script that turns off our mysql database and rsyncs the mysql folder to another. Afterwards mysql is turned on.

Later, mysql is accessed by either a bash script or by a web application.

After each restart, the first few queries that come in either through the bash script or webapp are really slow(stuff that takes 10 seconds takes 3 minutes). Once the slow queries finish or timeout, the queries run at normal speed. Also, when I login to mysql through the command line, all is fine afterwards and queries run at expected speeds.

I believe that the slowdown is because *normally* MySQL reads all the table information when I login(assuming no -A option is used) or after the first queries already access the necessary meta-table information.

My question is: How can I speed this process up through a bash script so I avoid the slow queries/manual login? Do I just do a dummy select on the necessary tables, or is there a smarter way getting the table information?

Environment:

- CentOS 5.8
- Mysql 5.1 with MyISAM engine

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `ANALYZE TABLE`?

Answer (score 2):

I would speculate that such a long lag in query time is due to the page cache being emptied when the server is rebooted.  Once a query has run, tables are loaded into the page cache and everything runs faster.

The first suggestion is to reload the page cache for the larger tables . . . you can do this just by doing a `select * from <table>` in your script.

This raises a question, though:  Why are the queries are doing full table scans?  If they are, you might have an opportunity to speed up the queries by using indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
The queries are not doing full table scans. The tables have indexes on them as well partitions. 
I have noticed that if I kill one of the queries and run it again,  it runs at normal speed. So I guess that page cache is where the problem is. 
For now I will try a dummy select on the big tables.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your database is losing its cached queries. Maybe try using stored procedures for queries you need to be fast on first run.

Answer (score 1):

Your query cache may be too large or be fragmented.

Take a look at this [this guide](http://www.learn4good.com/board/restarting-mysql-slow-with.html) that helps with tuning your database.